# bash vi key bindings: Can I map keys? Display mode (insert vs command)?

Tags: bash, vim, vi

I am a long time vi(m) user and recently made the switch to using vi key binding in bash.  I can already tell that this will be an improvement, but I would like to customize a few things to really become proficient.

1. I currently use the following mapping and it is totally entrenched: `map ii <esc>`.  Can I do the same on the command line?  It may seem trivial, but I am so used to just tapping i twice that reaching all the way up to the escape key is painful.
2. I would LOVE to find a way to indicate what mode I am in: insert or command.  This could take the from of changing the cursor type/color, putting a note in the prompt, etc.

I have looked through the man pages for bash and looked at creating an .inputrc file, but so far have come up with nothing that would work.  I see that you can map keys, but can you do it for two keys hit in rapid succession, like I do?

I have seen solutions out there that say they work for zsh.  I am not interested in switching to zsh.  If this is not possible in bash, I can live with it.

Comment: First question addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839006/map-jj-to-esc-in-inputrc-readline), second addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622943/zsh-vi-mode-status-line), but it's a _zsh_ answer. I know that zsh/bash prompt handling is different.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039713/different-bash-prompt-for-different-vi-editing-mode)

Comment: Cool... Thanks, pb2q, that first link is exactly what I needed.  Unfortunately, for now, it seems my second request above is just not possible yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your first request is possible by the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839006/map-jj-to-esc-in-inputrc-readline) linked in [pb2q](https://superuser.com/users/28608/pb2q)'s [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/463706/bash-vi-key-bindings-can-i-map-keys-display-mode-insert-vs-command#comment-544695) on your post.

Your second request is now possible if you have bash 4.3 and readline 6.3. Simply add this to your `.inputrc`:

```
set show-mode-in-prompt on
```

For me, it prepends a "+" to my prompt in insert mode, which changes to a ":" in command mode.

Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17144421/2093695) by [eMPee584](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200509/empee584) on StackOverflow.